# Get previous month's records in Netezza

Tags: netezza

What would be the correct syntax or the best way to grab the previous month's records in Netezza? I have data I need to query, I'm trying to find a way to use the current_date to pull the previous month. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a column in the table that contains the date you want to compare against?

Comment: The table contains records from all months, date_column. I was thinking I could use this months current date to get December records. I can do it in MySQL and sql server. But can’t do it for netezza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following using current_date and add_months.

select * from test_table order by 1 desc;

```
=> select * from test_table order by 1 desc;
 DATE_RECORD 
-------------
 2017-12-27
 2017-11-30
 2017-11-14
 2017-11-01
(4 rows)

    select date_record , current_date
    from test_table where 
    (date_record >= 
    add_months(date_trunc('month',current_date),-1))  and (date_record < (date_trunc('month',current_date)));

 DATE_RECORD |    DATE    
-------------+------------
 2017-11-30  | 2017-12-27
 2017-11-14  | 2017-12-27
 2017-11-01  | 2017-12-27
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a big help and turns out I found a huge coding error with this!